# SQL Join Tables on Closest Date BEFORE Shipped Date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, left-join, inner-join, closest

This may appear to be a repeat question but it is not because the other solutions in the forum don't work in this situation.

This is a query to our ERP database that is trying to get the final cost of goods sold total for parts.  Basically the ERP makes it easy to get all the direct costs out but doesn't calculate scrap costs.

Where I'm stuck is in the sub query in the FROM section marked:

`>>>>>>HELP NEEDED STARTING HERE`

The sub query, as it is now written, pulls out all the shipments to our scrap vendor and gets a monthly average rate per pound, then joins to the other tables based on alloy type, month and year.

My Finance Department has told me the average is not a good solution, since some metal prices fluctuate too much or they don't sell the scrap metal in the same month the parts shipped so this won't work.

I need to get the rate we are paid for scrap metal from the closest date before the part was shipped from our facility.

I've found other examples on Stack Overflow that show ways to do this but the main tables and the sub query tables overlap so the other solutions I've seen have failed.  I have commented in the code below to show and explain this.

I'm totally open to the idea I've approached this wrong. How can I make this work?

```
DECLARE @Date_From                      AS  DATETIME;
DECLARE @Date_To                        AS  DATETIME;
SET     @Date_From                      = '2016-10-01 00:00:00.000';
SET     @Date_To                        =  GETDATE()       ;
 -- Start Main query     
SELECT TOP 10
   CCustomer.Customer_Type          AS  'Industry'
  ,SShipper.Ship_Date               AS  'Ship_Date'
  ,SSContainer.Serial_No            AS  'Serial_No'
  ,PPart.Grade                      AS  'Alloy'
  ,tbl_ScrapValue.Scrap_Value_per_lb    AS 'Scap_Value_per_lb'

FROM
            Sales_v_Shipper_Line          AS SSLine 
      JOIN  Sales_v_Shipper               AS SShipper
        ON  SShipper.Shipper_Key = SSLine.Shipper_Key
      JOIN  Part_v_Part                   AS PPart
        ON  SSLine.Part_Key = PPart.Part_Key
      JOIN  Common_v_Customer             AS CCustomer
        ON  SShipper.Customer_No   = CCustomer.Customer_No
 -- >>>>>>HELP NEEDED STARTING HERE
 -- Below is the sub query that pulls the scrap sales value per pound.
 --  The key point is that both shipments to our customers of real parts,
 --   and the 'shipments' of scrap metal sales come from the same tables,
 --  mainly Part_v_Part and Sales_v_Shipper, because of that the other 
--solutions for the 'join by closest date' in the forums don't work.

LEFT OUTER  JOIN  (SELECT
                     MONTH(SShipper.Ship_Date)       AS 'Scrap_Ship_Month'
                    ,YEAR(SShipper.SHip_Date)        AS 'Scrap_Ship_Year'
                    ,PPart.Grade                     AS  'Alloy'
                    ,AVG(AARIDist.Unit_Price)        AS 'Scrap_Value_per_lb'

                FROM
                        Sales_v_Shipper               AS  SShipper
                  JOIN  Sales_v_Shipper_Line          AS  SS_Line
                    ON  SShipper.Shipper_Key = SS_Line.Shipper_Key  
                  JOIN  Part_v_Part                   AS PPart
                    ON  SS_Line.Part_Key = PPart.Part_Key
                  JOIN  Common_v_Customer             AS  CCustomer
                    ON  SShipper.Customer_No = CCustomer.Customer_No

                WHERE CCustomer.Customer_Code     = 'Scrap_Vendor'
                AND SSHipper.Ship_Date <= @Date_To

            GROUP BY
                 MONTH(SShipper.Ship_Date)
                ,YEAR(SShipper.SHip_Date)
                ,PPart.Grade
               ) AS tbl_ScrapValue
  ON  PPart.Grade = tbl_ScrapValue.Alloy 
      AND
        YEAR(SShipper.Ship_Date) = YEAR(tbl_ScrapValue.Scrap_Ship_Year)
      AND
        MONTH(SShipper.Ship_Date) =(tbl_ScrapValue.Scrap_Ship_Month)

--- >>>>HELP NEEDED ENDS HERE
WHERE
    AND SShipper.Ship_Date >= @Date_From
    AND SSHipper.Ship_Date <= @Date_To      
 GROUP BY
      SShipper.Shipper_No
      ,SShipper.Ship_Date
      ,CCustomer.Customer_Type
      ,SSContainer.Quantity
      ,PPart.Grade
```

Here's a sample output from the query above, as you can see the 'Scrap_Value_per_lb' is failing:

```
[![Sample_Output][1]][1]

Industry              Ship_Date         Serial_No Alloy Scap_Value_per_lb
Material Processing 17-Oct-16 4:47:00 PM S472091  C182 NULL 
Material Processing 17-Oct-16 4:47:00 PM S472210  C182 NULL 
Material Processing 17-Oct-16 4:47:00 PM S472211  C182 NULL 
Electronics         17-Oct-16 4:27:00 PM S436738  C180 NULL 
Electronics         17-Oct-16 4:27:00 PM S463290  C180 NULL 
Electronics         17-Oct-16 4:27:00 PM S463315  C180 NULL 
Electronics         17-Oct-16 4:27:00 PM S463327  C180 NULL 
Electronics         17-Oct-16 4:27:00 PM S463333  C180 NULL 
Electronics         17-Oct-16 4:27:00 PM S463345  C180 NULL 
Electronics         17-Oct-16 4:27:00 PM S463354  C180 NULL
```

### Update

This was edited a second time @7am 10/19/2016 to simplify code further, added comments in code to clarify based on feedback from others.

Comment: And that's the shortest example of your problem you can come up with? Don't just dump your code here, make a short example.

Comment: @JamesZ, this is a short example and I've spent about 30 minutes cutting out a lot.  I guess there is always to cut away more but this is about 25% of what I started with.
I'll make some edits based on your feedback but I want to stress this was not a straight up dump of my code.

Comment: What version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: Unfortunately at least I can't figure out what the problem is here, there's so many tables and joins that it makes it tough to figure it out. Maybe instead of join you need to use outer apply with select top 1 + have there order by the date desc?

Comment: @FeryalBadili, T-SQL, thanks for chiming in!

Comment: @JamesZ, CROSS APPLY might be the answer - the problem I'm having is that we list our scrap vendor as customer and ship the scrap to him so the inner query tables and outer query tables are the same. 
Effectively I'm trying to match 2 shipments from the same tables based on the closest match by date.   One shipment to a real customer and then the shipment with the closest date before the real shipment to our scrap vendor.  Also, I get error messages when I try to order by date desc in the inner query.
Thanks again for helping!

Comment: I really think that you need to use cross apply. Take a look at this example: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/2516/cross-apply-outer-apply#t=201610191336553371315

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent a couple of hours thinking about this question and boiled the sample code down even further and [re-posted the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40175049/t-sql-join-table-on-self-based-on-closest-date).

I think it makes more sense and I thank all of you who responded and tried to help answer what I wrote.  It helped but I still could not get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand it correctly, you want the sub query to return only ONE row (Same for every row in the outer query?)

```
SELECT Top 1 
                     SShipper.Ship_Date
                    ,PPart.Grade                AS  'Alloy'
                    ,AARIDist.Unit_Price        AS 'Scrap_Value_per_lb'

                FROM
                        Sales_v_Shipper               AS  SShipper
                  JOIN  Sales_v_Shipper_Line          AS  SS_Line
                    ON  SShipper.Shipper_Key = SS_Line.Shipper_Key  
                  JOIN  Part_v_Part                   AS PPart
                    ON  SS_Line.Part_Key = PPart.Part_Key
                  JOIN  Common_v_Customer             AS  CCustomer
                    ON  SShipper.Customer_No = CCustomer.Customer_No
                  JOIN  Accounting_v_AR_Invoice_Dist  AS  AARIDist
                    ON  SS_Line.Shipper_Line_Key = AARIDist.Shipper_Line_Key

                WHERE CCustomer.Customer_Code     = 'Scrap_Value'
                AND SSHipper.Ship_Date <= @Date_To
                AND AARIDIst.Unit_Price < AARIDist.Quantity
                AND AARIDist.Unit_Price > '0'

                Order By SShipper.Ship_Date Desc

               ) AS tbl_SValue
```

If the value of the sub query should be different for each row of the outer query, then I need to know how each row in the sub query is joined to the row in the outer query

Comment: I want to join the sub query to the rows in the outer query based on a match of PPart.Grade (aliased as 'Alloy') and the scrap shipment date being the closest one to the shipment date of the part.  The I think problem I'm having is that we list our scrap vendor as customer and ship the scrap to him so the inner query tables and outer query tables are the same. Effectively I'm trying to match 2 shipments from the same tables based on the closest match by date.  Because of that all the other potential solutions I've found don't work.

Answer (score 0):

So when you sell a metal of a certain alloy, you sell everything that's available, i.e. no remainders?

Then you take the records from the buying table and join them with the next selling record for the same alloy. This can be achieved with a cross apply. Here is a query with simple tables to give you the idea what's needed:

```
select
  year(matched_sold.sold_date),
  month(matched_sold.sold_date),
  sum(bought.amount * bought.price)
from bought
cross apply
(
  select top 1 *
  from sold
  where sold.alloy = bought.alloy
  and sold.sold_date > bought.bought_date
  order by sold.sold_date desc
) matched_sold
group by
  year(matched_sold.sold_date),
  month(matched_sold.sold_date);
```

Comment: We sell metal parts to 'real' customers and sell scrap metal removed during  manufacturing to the scrap yard.
We list our scrap vendor as customer and ship the scrap to him like other products so the used inner query tables and outer query tables are the same. Effectively I'm trying to match 2 shipments from the same tables based on the closest match by date. The outer query is shipments to real customers, the inner query gets shipments to the scrap yard from which I derive a price per pound to get COGS.
I'm trying to join these based on alloy and closest previous date.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, whether I got your problem right. You want to join two result sets by using a JOIN on a date field, where there are no exact matches guaranteed. Possibly you could use the ROW_NUMBER function to generate partitioned row numbers including a sort and then join on the row numbers with e.g. ROW_NR = 1.

```
TABLE 1                 TABLE 2
ROW_NR DATE       ID    ROW_NR DATE       ID
------ ---------- --    ------ ---------- --
     1 10/25/2016  1 -match- 1 10/27/2016  1 
     2 10/24/2016  1        
     3 10/20/2016  1
     4 10/19/2016  1
     1 10/23/2016  2 -match- 1 10/28/2016  2
     2 10/15/2016  2        
     3 10/09/2016  2
     4 10/08/2016  2
```

**Row Numbering in Table 1:**

- Data for TABLE1 with TABLE1.DATE <= TABLE2.DATE
- Partitioned by ID
- Sorted by ID and DATE DESC

**Row Numbering in Table 2:**

- ROW_NR is always 1

With that you can join implicitly on the data fields without an exact match. Sorry for not providing a SQL Statement.